# When running an app, how to modify/add a class file and then run it?

Tags: android, auto-update

In my case, I want to download a new `.class` file to update some parts of the old application. Could it be possible and how?

Or is there any other way to download data and update just part of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred Chung wrote a great post about class loading on the android developers blog a while ago.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

PS: And yes there are other ways to update your app. Just upload it to the market :)

Comment: thanks. I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to do what you want with `.class` files.

However, you should design your application in such a way that when you download new data (not `.class` files) from your server, it should save it (optional) and present it using any preferred View type.

Comment: but I want to implement a module to take care of the update procedures automatically.

Comment: then simply update your application (.apk) with that new module and push that updated version to the user